# Inifinite scrolling PageView

Tags: flutter

I want to create this date picker [image: Date picker] There is total of 7 days, but when I scroll. I would like to set it to the middle again and change only a variable. How can I do that?

```
Expanded(
  child: PageView.builder(
    onPageChanged: (value) => {},
    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.175, initialPage: 3),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount:  7,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Date(index: index),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [loop_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/loop_page_view) package. follow these steps:

1- Open a terminal or cmd in your project directory, paste this command and press enter:

```
flutter pub add loop_page_view
```

2- Change `PageView.builder` to `LoopPageView.builder` in your code:

```
Expanded(
  child: LoopPageView.builder(
    onPageChanged: (value) => {},
    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.175, initialPage: 3),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount:  7,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Date(index: index),
  ),
),
```

3- Done!